# What would cause my IPv6 connectivity to keep dying, with a reboot fixing it each time?

Tags: centos, linux-networking, ipv6, networkmanager

Centos 8 Stream

When I first boot my server up, ipv6 works fine.  I can ping another ipv6 address without issue.

A few (10?) minutes later, it stops working.  Rebooting the box fixes it, but I can't be rebooting a webserver every ten minutes.

Anyone come across this before and have any idea what the issue might be?

I didn't used to have this issue.  What's changed is I've had a 10G card added to the server.  It now has that and the pre-existing 1G card.  I'm only using the 10G card.  My `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` only has one file, aligning to the card I'm using.  Do I need another file for the other card disabling it in some way?

Cockpit tells me that Network Manager Wait Online is failing on every boot - I have a feeling that's ALWAYS been the case, but I can't be certain.

I just tried manually starting that, and it worked, and I lost the ability to ping IPv6 immediately.  However the logs show that it's not started under its own steam at all today, so I think that's a red herring.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: IPv6 depends on ICMPv6 for link-layer resolution the same way IPv4 depends on ARP. Could it be you installed custom firewall rules that drop ICMPv6 including those needed for NDP/SLAAC?

Comment: After having fought with this issue all day I relented and asked my webhost for assistance, knowing I'd probably have to pay for their time.  They replied in minutes, saying "we now have set the ARP-Entries again for your IPs. Please check, if the problem is now resolved.".  When I asked if this was something I should have done (and known to do) or if it was something on one of their systems they replied with "The named issue does not seem to be a configuration failure from your site on the first view. If the issue should persist again, we will look into it deeper with you."

Comment: Which sounds to me like it was something they screwed up but they don't want to say as much.  Very apt that I spent all of Friday 13th fighting an issue that was out of my control without realising it was 